# Using Javascript to input time in HTML5 time field

Tags: javascript, html, time, input

I'm trying to create a function in JS that will fill in the html5 `<input type=time>` with a format like this `hh:mm:ss`.

```
function timeChange(){
var d = new Date();
d.getHours();
d.getMinutes();
d.getSeconds();

var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("time_in").value = (....);
}
```

I'm not sure how to code the .value for this. I've tried using `.value = (hours":"minutes":"seconds);` but that just gives me a compile error.

Anyone got ideas? I just need it in hh:mm:ss.

HTML5 code:

```
 <button type="button" onClick="timeChange()">Time</button>

 <input id="time_in" type="time" name="time_in">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hours":"minutes":"seconds` isn't concatenating the string, you need `+`s: `hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds`

Comment: @Envious No worries, it happens to all of us

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
// Need to create UTC time of which fields are same as local time.
d.setUTCHours(d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), 0);
document.getElementById("time_in").valueAsDate = d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('time_in').value = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

Otherwise you're not creating one concatenated string.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to grab the time string from the Date object:

`var time = (new Date()).toTimeString().split(' ')[0];`

The split allows us to remove the timezone portion of the string.